# int test in C# TestServer with TestStartup throws Not Found

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I managed to create a TestServer that works fine with Startup.

```
public TestAdminServer()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Test")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

        _testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        _testServer.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
    }
```

But when I would like to change Startup to my TestStartup located in UnitTest, it works neither as a full copy of Startup or just simple inheritance

```
    public class TestStartup : Startup
    {
       public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
       {}
```

The controller just returns a simple Dto list (I suspected the service creation so I commented it) and there is nothing appsettings related (now) in startups.

Where I could look the error for? I found no error throwed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `TestStartup` resides in different assembly than `Startup` class. It's the main reason why host is not able to locate controllers as entry point is different.

Depending on the ASP.NET Core version you are using, the solution might be slightly different.

In `TestStartup` class override following method: (make sure that in `Startup` classthe same method is marked as virtual)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{                
    services.AddControllers().AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
}
```

You can also refer to [Anthony Giretti's .NET blog post](https://anthonygiretti.com/2021/04/16/testserver-asp-net-core-5-fix-system-invalidoperationexception-solution-root-could-not-be-located-using-application-root-with-a-custom-startup-file/)